# Ignoring folder in Sublime Text 3, but not all with same name

Tags: sublimetext3

I'm having a project in Sublime Text 3. I want to ignore `/vendor` folder (in the root of my project) from searching, but not all folders named `vendor`. For now I have this:

```
{
    "folders":
    [
        {
            "folder_exclude_patterns":
            [
                "vendor",
            ],
            "path": "."
        }
    ]
}
```

But the problem is that it also excludes `/resources/views/vendor` folder and a couple of other folders.

I know I can also put absolute path there, like this:

```
"folder_exclude_patterns":
[
    "/Users/me/www/my-project/vendor",
]
```

It works as desired, but makes it non-portable. I would need to change this file each time I move the project and, even worse, all teammates would need to change it themselves or keep the same project path. Not good at all.

How can I exclude folder relatively to the project root?